# Get value of checked radio button before submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to get checked radio button before submitting form, and to pass the value in another page via POST, how I can do that?
This is my php code, in form's action where is check, I want to put checked radio button.

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $user["nome"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user["role"];?></td>
    <td class='right'>
        <form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']?>&user=<?php echo $user["nome"];?>&sub=<?php echo $sub . $user["nome"];?>&check=' method='post'>
            <label>
                <input type='radio' name=<?php echo $user["nome"];?> id='c'  value='1' <?php echo ($user["role"] == 'configuratore')? 'checked:''; ?> />C
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type='radio' name=<?php echo $user["nome"]; ?> id='va' value='2' <?php echo ($user["role"] == 'visualizzatore avanzato')? 'checked':'' />VA
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type='radio' name=<?php echo $user["nome"] ;?> id='v' value='3' <?php echo ($user["role"] == 'visualizzatore')? 'checked':''?> />V
            </label>
            <input type='submit' name='sub_<?php echo $user["nome"] ' value='Cambia'/>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far...

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to all the checkboxes say `checkboxclass`and then in jquery write

```
$(".checkboxclass:checked").each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
})
```

this would alert all the checked chek boxes value.